# Reading from CSV file in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

In the below code i am able to read from a comma seperated textarea and store data into arrays. The textarea has an ID of 'input2' and all the values are passed from input2 to variable 'input' in the function.

How would i achieve the same by reading a csv file rather than from the textarea?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<h1>CSV parser</h1>
<p>We will attempt to parse a CSV file</p>

<button type="button" onclick="example2()">Load the CSV file</button> 

<br><br>

 <textarea id="input2" style="height:150px;">"All work","and no play","makes     Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."
"All work","and no play","makes Jack","a dull boy..."</textarea>

<br><br>

<table id="result2" border="1"></table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script></script>
<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js">        </script>

<script>

    function example2() {
      var input = $('#input2').val();
      var data = $.csv.toArrays(input);
      var html = generateTable(data);
      $('#result2').empty();
      $('#result2').html(html);
    }

    function generateTable(data) {
      var html = '';

      if(typeof(data[0]) === 'undefined') {
        return null;
      }

      if(data[0].constructor === Array) {
        for(var row in data) {
          html += '<tr>\r\n';
          for(var item in data[row]) {
            html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
          }
          html += '</tr>\r\n';
        }
      }

  return html;
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The documentation gives you one [example](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/examples/file-handling.html) on how to read a csv using FileReader object.

Comment: The csv file is alongside my index.html file. I know the position of the file ....